# Angular deployment de proyecto en distintos ambientes

Tags: angular

tengo la siguiente inquietud: una pagina desarrollada en angular (unico proyecto) para ser usada por distintos clientes (intranet), la pagina se va a publicar en un servidor de pruebas y posteriormente produccion.

Mi pagina consume un servicio web en cual por las actividades inherentes del negocio, este servicio se va a consumir desde una vpn que el cliente facilitara. (cada cliente - unico webservice )

Una de las practicas es colocar en el environment.ts la url, pero si estamos hablando del mismo aplicativo para varios clientes, como puedo simplemente modificar los archivos generados por el build para cambiar la url del archivo environment? se puede crear una especie de archivo .settings el cual me sirva para tener la url del webService que la pagina consume sin neecesidad de compilar el proyecto cambiando el environment por cada cliente?

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Las opciones que tienes para manejar las configuraciones aparte de los environments:

1. Crear un archivo de javascript con las configuraciones, y guardar las variables en el window he importarlo en index.html. Podrías crear un servicio para consumir las variables o en un `environment.ts` que no sea remplazado. No es una solución tan elegante pero resuelve el problema.

**Ejemplo**

**Estructura de Proyecto**

```
- src/
-- app/
-- assets/
-- environments/
...
-- config.js
-- window.d.ts
-- angular.json
```

**config.js**

```
window.URL = `https://www...`
window.ASSETS = `https://www...`
```

**angular.json**

Lo más recomendable es que actualiaces el `angular.json` para que te asegurares que el `config.js` sea copiado cuando se hace un build (en caso de que sea necesario).

```
"scripts": [
 { "input": "./config.js", "inject": false, "bundleName": "config" }
]
```

Es importante el `inject: false` el cual evita incluir el script dentro del bundle.

**window.d.ts**
Crea un `window.d.ts` para poder extender la interface de windows y asi puedas mantener "tipado" el proyecto.

```
interface Config {
  URL: string
  ASSETS: string
}

declare global {
  interface Window {
    CONFIG: Config
  }
}
```

**config.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigService {

  constructor() { }

  get() {
    return window.CONFIG
  }

}
```

Cada vez que corras `npm run build` el `config.js` va ser copiado al `/dist`. Desde ahi puedes hacer las modificaciones que necesites para cada proyecto.

2. La otra opción es utilizar un API/servicio en cargado de retornar las configuraciones pero eso ya es una decisión arquitectural que debes de tomar.